# ArcPy 10.1 PointGeometry.projectAs()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, add-in

I'm trying to reproject an X,Y passed in from an Add-in.

So far this works fine:

```
pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x,y),srIn,False, False)
projectedPoint = pointGeometry.projectAs(srOut)
```

Based on `projectAs (spatial_reference, {transformation_name})`

I should be able to pass in the transformation_name, but I have no idea where a list of constants may be (says it's a string)?

In .NET I would use 'OSGB1936_To_WGS1984_2', for the transformation I am after.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 8 hours for some odd reason.

As always things are clearer in the morning. 

For anyone else doing anything similar the transformations list is here: 

`arcpy.ListTransformations()`

Answer (score 1):

As commented by the asker:

> For anyone else doing anything similar the transformations list is
>   here: arcpy.ListTransformations()

[ListTransformations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listtransformations.htm):

> Returns a list of valid transformation methods for converting data
>   from one spatial reference to another. An extent can be used to narrow
>   the list of valid transformation methods for a specific geographic
>   area.